# JavaScript search bar popup

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it was possible to type in code into a search bar and make it show a JavaScript popup without having to use console commands or a website and if so how would i do it i have tried looking it up but i couldn't find anything

The specific line of code i was looking to use was

```
window.alert("`Sampletext`");
```

Also should i not be using JavaScript for something like this but instead use c#, html or something else

Comment: What do you mean by search bar? The browser's search bar? A search bar on a web page?

Comment: Take a moment to think about the security implications if that was something that sites actually allowed.

Comment: You can run code as bookmarklet if that's what you mean

Comment: yes i mean a bookmarklet

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly what you are trying to do, but consider using the prompt function:

```js
var toRun = prompt("Enter some code");
eval(toRun);
```

Be careful with eval though, it can be unsafe.

Comment: While technically true, `eval` is evil and should never be used like this. In fact, it should probably never be used.

Comment: I agree, but I was not sure what the question was and this was one possibility.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Yes a bookmarklet would be best.